# Kentor/Sustainsys redirects back to SP after receiving LogoutResponse from IDP

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2, single-logout

In my application Kentor v.21 single logout works fine for different IDP-s. However one particular IDP after logging out sends the LogoutResponse back to SP. In SP log I see the line: `Received logout response _9b1700c5-6f58-43aa-8b63-a2a4ad6fa3f2, redirecting to https://mysp.url/home/` . I am not sure where does this URL come from, but in the result, the user gets logged back into the SP app. Is there a way to configure it on SP side to redirect to some other page?

Answer (score 1):

After the logout response is received, a redirect is done to the URL specified when initiating the logout (through authprops or query string). And if none was specified, the default return url from the config is used.

You can also intercept and alter the redirect location by overriding the `LogoutCommandResultCreated` notification and alter the `Location` property on the `CommandResult`

Comment: I tried to add return URL to my logout link so now it is something like /AuthServices/Logout?ReturnUrl=/Signout. I am testing against sustainsys stubidp, but don't see how it affects the logout process. After I click my logout link I get to sustainsys Single Logout screen. It says something like SP Single Logout Url: http://localhost:33333/Logout. It is not correct URL and it is not clear what to do to change it to the correct http://localhost:33333/Signout.

Comment: Follow through the process. The IDP will always redirect to /AuthServices/LogOut with the LogOut response. After that there will be a redirect to the supplied URL.